# Execute same operation on several pairs of files with similar names

Tags: shell-script, filenames

So I several large data files that correspond to temperature and vapor in the form tmp_information_about_dataset.file and vap_information_about_dataset.file

So for every tmp_... file there is a corresponding vap_... file, I'll use both datasets to perform some calculations on and then generate a corresponding output file in the form out_information_about_dataset.file

Just to be clear, each pair of tmp/vap files, after information about the datasets (ie any characters after tmp or vap) are identical, so I'll also want the characters after `out` to be identical to information about the datasets from which it was generated.
eg

```
 tmp_123ABC456_model1_2010.nc
 vap_123ABC456_model1_2010.nc
 out_123ABC456_model1_2010.nc

 tmp_123CDF_model2_2010.nc
 vap_123CDF_model2_2010.nc
 out_123CDF_model2_2010.nc
```

Is there a way in which I am able to take all the files in the dictionary, perform the calculation on matching pairs and name the output file with an identical file name after the first 3 characters?

I was thinking something [like this answer here would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory) but the fact I need to use to two files with corresponding name, as opposed to any file in the dictionary as well as want separate output files, is throwing me off a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, iterate over all `tmp_` files:

```
for file in tmp_*; do
```

then, for each `tmp_` file, you can get the corresponding `vap_` file with `vap${file#tmp}` - first, `${file#tmp}` removes the tmp prefix (the variable itself is not modified), then the result is concatenated with `vap`.

```
for file in tmp_*; do ./process_stuff "${file}" "vap${file#tmp}" > "out${file#tmp}"; done
```

Comment: How might this be altered if I wanted to do the same thing, but also change the last part of the file name? For example if I was copying a .txt file and I wanted the identifier to be the same as the corresponding tmp_123.nc.txt file, resulting in `tmp_123.txt`? I've tried pattern replacement along with mv like this `${tmp//.nc/.txt}` but get a syntax error and not sure what the  issue is

Comment: note, I am not changing the file type here, a .txt file is created from the name of the .nc file, which includes the .nc part, which I want removed

Comment: @Maitiu You can use `${tmp#.nc.txt}.txt` to remove the `.nc.txt` from the end and stick just the `.txt` back